# How to resample a grouped data frame with start and end times?

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a similar question before but I am trying to resample a dataframe with tick data to minute data such that the beginning and ending of the resulting time series encompasses the beginning of the day of the earliest time stamp and the end of the day of the last time stamp. I have some sample code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Code': pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], dtype='str'), 
'Timestamp': pd.Series([1608627600073933, 1698929600124359, 1608627600073933, 1608929600124359], dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
'Val':[5, 6, 5, 6]})
df.set_index(['Timestamp'], inplace=True)
df.groupby('Code').resample('1T').agg('sum')
```

The above code creates a dataframe that starts and ends with the first and last available tick data, but I would like it to begin and end at their respective points of the day.

It also ignores the grouping of the data by code and just gives a single time series with out codes.

The resulting dataframe should have 5760 rows since it encompasses 1440 minutes over 2 days for 2 codes. (1440 x 2 x 2)

Answer (score 1):

Use `origin='start'` or `origin='end'` but you can't have the both:

```
>>> df.groupby('Code').resample('T', origin='start').sum()
                                    Val
Code Timestamp                         
A    1970-01-19 14:50:27.600073933    5
     1970-01-19 14:51:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:52:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:53:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:54:27.600073933    0
...                                 ...
B    1970-01-19 14:51:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:52:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:53:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:54:27.600073933    0
     1970-01-19 14:55:27.600073933    6

[1512 rows x 1 columns]
```

```
>>> df.groupby('Code').resample('T', origin='end').sum()
                                    Val
Code Timestamp                         
A    1970-01-19 14:50:29.600124359    5
     1970-01-19 14:51:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:52:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:53:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:54:29.600124359    0
...                                 ...
B    1970-01-19 14:51:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:52:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:53:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:54:29.600124359    0
     1970-01-19 14:55:29.600124359    6

[1512 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: At least for what I would like is for me to have both. I may be on to something by appending a midnight and a 23:59:00 time stamp for each code prior to aggregation but I have yet to figure out how to in the best way.